# How to have windows 10 send email upon unlocking?

Tags: email, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I followed the tutorial [How To Get Email Notifications Whenever Someone Logs Into Your Computer](http://web.archive.org/web/20161229165753/http://www.howtogeek.com/123568/how-to-get-email-notifications-whenever-someone-logs-into-your-computer/), but it doesn't take care of PC unlocking (log in after Win+L). Did I miss anything? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0):

The unlock operation doesn't count as a logon. As such your tutorial doesn't cover that case. If you go ahead and check the available Triggers for Tasks created by the Task Scheduler you will find that there is also a Trigger for workstation lock/unlock that you might use.

Comment: Thanks @Seth. I tried that one, with no luck.

Comment: Could you maybe get into a tiny bit more detail what you mean by that? How did you set it up? What was the result of the run using that setup? What worked and didn't work?

Comment: Thanks again for your comment. This [screenshot](http://imgur.com/Y2XpTh4) shows my configuration. It works if the "Run" is manually clicked, otherwise, it won't work.

Comment: Did you check what the `Last Run Result` column says after you unlock the WS? It might actually be an error that happens that prevents it from running successfully.

Comment: Thanks, @Seth. As you may see from this new [screenshot](http://imgur.com/Mlxo9uG), the task ran successfully last time, but it was triggered by clicking the "Run" manually, not by "unlocking" the PC. I tried locking and unlocking the PC several times, not even once the task was triggered. This is rather weird.

Comment: Did you make sure to also set it to run without a logged on user? Essentially it's the same as in the tutorial just with a different/additional trigger (you can setup both triggers). If there wasn't any status it's really kind of strange.